# Lock mechanism for Queue<T> during Enqueue and Dequeue

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

In Queue, enqueue and dequeue both need a write lock. Why would someone use ReaderWriterLockSlim versus just using lock{}? As an example,

Using ReaderWriterLockSlim

```
qLock.EnterWriteLock(); 
try 
{ 
    localQ.Enqueue(item); // or localQ.Dequeue(item)
} 

finally 
{ 
    qLock.ExitWriteLock(); 
}
```

Versus lock{}

```
try 
{ 
    lock(qLock) { localQ.Enqueue(item);} // or localQ.Dequeue(item)
}
```

Comment: @Davita, brian's answer is wrong in this case (but true usually).  It's unfortunate it has 3 up-votes.

Comment: thanks to everybody's response. Unfortunately, I don't think I have my answer yet. I get the Peek() part with EnterReadLock() but if my logic is just Enqueue() and Dequeue() I need EnterWriterLock() regardless. If I am in a lock{} and says it's acquisition is delayed indefinite or say very long; lock offers no fault tolerance and it's possible to get into deadlock or a blocking scenario. Wouldn't  ReaderWriterLock or ReaderWriterLockSlim offer me a fault tolerance option to avoid the deadlock or long blocking. thoughts? or am I off the course here

Answer (score 5):

**The use of `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is primarily a performance optimization in scenarios where there are many threads reading from a resource often but only a few threads writing to it.**

The Monitor class (used by the lock statement) acquires an exclusive lock on the resource - which means that both readers and writers are blocked. In many cases, however, reading is much more frequent than writing. In those scenarios, the use of a reader/writer lock allows multiple readers to enter the locks simultaneously but only one writer at a time (when all queued readers are out).

In your example the a reader/writer lock *only makes sense if there is other code that peeks at the queue without dequeing an item* ... otherwise all operations are mutating writes, and a `lock` statement would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that would still permit readers to `Peek` without requiring a write `lock`. It's hard to imagine a scenario where this is practically useful though.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` does not provide any real advantage.  You're right that both `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` are write operations and would require an exclusive write lock.

For a collection that does have read operations, as most collections do, then `ReaderWriterLockSlim` would be better than always using `lock`.

The only small advantage I could think of is consistency.  If in most places `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is used because most other collections are used for a lot of reads and few writes, then it can be easier for development and maintenance to just use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` everywhere.